# Laravel 4 scalable design using Repository Pattern (backed by Eloquent) and Caching

Tags: php, caching, laravel-4, repository-pattern, dao

Hello amazing StackOverflow users, hope you can help me with some answers and opinions.

I'm designing a system where Laravel 4 was chosen as framework.
I faced problems trying to unit test due to the ActiveRecord complexity, which Laravel uses through Eloquent.

Looking at that I came across the Repository Pattern to be a good alternative and at the same time it also allows me to create my own set of libraries that can be easily detached and not dependent on the Framework.

With that said, I started using it and it has allowed for nice unit test integration and use of IoC. (I created my our own Plain Old Objects and within the repositories I map between the Eloquent model and these entities)

**So far so good**, but now here are my two main problems:

- A) How to easily add Caching?
- B) How to keep Caching consistency when multiple repositories are using the Eloquent models?

---

## For A)

I was reading the Laravel documentation and some posts on the web, and it seems the that even when enabling caching (memcache) on the configuration file, the only way to actually use it is by creating a `QueryBuilder` instance from the model, and then using the `remember()` method.

But this requires that every Repository that makes use of the model, creates a builder and developers remember to use the `remember()` method.

Am I missing something? Is there a better way for this?

The only way I could think of, is to override the `newBaseQueryBuilder()` method on the Eloquent specific model and call the `remember()` method before returning the instance, but feels kinda hacky.

*However, I noticed that performing Update operations won't clear the cache, so it feels quite useless, for caching data will potentially return no longer valid values.*

---

## For B)

If I have multiple repositories that affect the same Model, since cache don't clear well, if we start using the `Cache` Facade to handle caching separately, it will very quickly become unmanageable, unscalable and susceptible to bugs.

Reading some posts and blogs (http://culttt.com/2014/02/03/laravel-4-cache-service/) and has some good ideas basically to use a **Decorator Pattern** so we make a Cachable implementation of the repository.

However, though this is a good idea, the issue comes with the problem stated on A), many repositories affecting the same model thus unmaintainable to handle the same cache value for an object consistently throughout different repositories.

---

**Here is where I ask for solutions you may have thought of or implemented, as well as opinions on my following idea.**

#### Idea

- Keep using the Repository Pattern (however, not make it implementation specific to the ORM, i.e. `EloquentUserRepository`)
- Use the Data Access Object pattern to wrap the models.
- My DAOs will in turn will provide an Eloquent specific implementation.
- Use the Decorator Pattern on the DAOs to provide the caching layer and because of the pattern, it allows me to also keep the Caching logic pretty centric, and loosely coupled.
- Make the Repositories use DAOs
- Using service providers, I could potentially have different caching mechanisms depending on the objects (static data would use APC, while more volatile data will be on Memcache, and others maybe on Membase perhaps)

  .

Thank you for all your help and opinions.

Comment: This helped me to decide: https://laracasts.com/forum/?p=718-repository-pattern-and-eloquent-models/p1#p3546

Answer (score 0):

Jeffrey Way does a lot of testing and has written alot on this subject for laravel. Here is an artical i have come across for testing in models. It may or may not help. - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/testing-like-a-boss-in-laravel-models--net-30087

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajoFwWwSHTI